# Dynamic Label in Scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

I want to achieve the following:

1. I have two Arrays

   ```
    NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese bla blub",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanee",@"German",@"German",@"German",@"German",@"German",nil];

    NSMutableArray *languageArray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hier kommt nun was ganz langes, jetzt mach ich das noch länger, damit der scheiß auch wirklich funktioniert.",@"Spanish jetzt hist hier auch mehr drin das sieht ja super aus wieviel bekomme ich den hier rein ",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian ajkslasdöadfnaklsdmnklsd",@"Japanese",@"German",@"German",@"German hier steht jetzt was ganz langes drin",@"German",@"German",nil];
   ```
2. I have a `UIScrollView`
3. As you can See my `ObjectAtIndex:0` in both arrays are differently by content as well as length
4. I want to set for each Object in My Array a label that is for Array 1 an the left site of the screen and the other starts at the end of label 1.

Like this pic.

[See this link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B39VLJYVNyVgNEhRLTNjRkk1c1E/edit?usp=sharing)

How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you to take Tableview rather than taking a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic height to `UILable` using my this method:

```
-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use it like below:

```
UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[lblAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
lblAddress.text = @"your Text ";
lblAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
lblAddress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                         200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); 

lblAddress.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[self.view addSubview:lblAddress];
```

and then set `UIScrollView's` content size like bellow..

```
float fscrview = lblAddress.frame.origin.y + lblAddress.frame.size.height + 20;
yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
```